# MVC helper to insert html by finding container

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have 2 custom html helpers

```
@html.Grid(blah...).blah...
@html.Pagination()
```

the problem I am facing is that Pagination will depend on the data of grid, but can be before or after it is called. I need them separate to allow placement of the paging content at the bottom or top of the page instead of touching the grid.

so this is an example page:

```
@html.Pagination()
@html.Grid(blah...).blah...
@html.Pagination()
```

I have figured out that I can share data between Grid and Pagination if pagination is after grid, but before is still a problem. I have thought of making an empty container and modifying the html output of it in Grid, but I can't seem to figure that out. I want it this way so that I can do this:

```
@html.Pagination()
@html.Grid().Columns(...).AjaxPaging();
@html.Pagination()
```

If it is not possible or easily done, I can settle for putting "AjaxPaging()" and the model on both of the Pagination and the Grid, but I would like the Pagination to be dummy containers and let the grid do all the work.

Also, Javascript is not an option, as I also want HtmlPaging (working without js enabled) for those who disable js on websites. I could easily do it with Ajax or JS.

Thanks.

Comment: This is just not something the razor viewengine handles natively.  And the unfortunate choice of a fluid API instead of a model severely limits your options - to the point that I'm not sure its even possible.  If you switch to using a model you get all kinds of options.

Comment: by using a model do you mean building a model specifically catered for both my Pagination and Grid, and set the type of paging in the model? If so I get the concept, but I have never done it in practice (still fairly new to MVC), do I have to make a class for the model, or is this something better done on the fly? a quick simple example would be great! thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Model example:

```
class GridModel {
  public List<GridColumn> Columns {get; set;}
  /*  rest of model, including pagination properties  */
}
```

Your controller would do the work of building the model object.

View Code:

```
/* `model` is of type `GridModel` */

@html.Pagination(model)
@html.Grid(model)
@html.Pagination(model)
```